# choosing input file with -f flag

Tags: file-io

How can I use the "-f" flag with the ./a.out command to choose an input file in C++? For example, if the input file is "inputfile.txt" then the following command line should choose that file as the input file:
./a.out -f inputfile.txt

Does anyone know the code involved in choosing the input file in this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program `a.out` to use the `-f` flag you need to write the code to handle this. See [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson14.html) C++ tutorial on command line arguments for more information.

If you want your program to take it's input from a file instead of `stdin` then you can simple use the redirection operator `<` like this:

`./a.out < inputfile.txt`